# Symfony 4 CollectionType Constraints - array of strings

Tags: php, json, forms, symfony, validation

I have a very simple array of strings being stored in a database and provided via an API.

Using Symfony's form types I'm adding validation for various bits of data.

I've hit a wall with a `CollectionType` that is essentially an array of strings, for example:

`['key', 'words', 'are', 'the', 'best']`

With the form code:

```php
->add('keywords', CollectionType::class, [
    'allow_add' => true,
    'constraints' => [
        new Count(['min' => 1]),
        new NotBlank(['allowNull' => false])
    ]
])
```

This is allowing the following to pass the constraints:

`[null]` and `['']`

If I can figure out what I'm doing wrong I'd like to add Regex validation to each element as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove empty elements, [`delete_empty`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#delete-empty) should do the trick and you could remove `NotBlank`.

To apply additional validation to the elements, you'll have to pass the constraint to the collection *item*, not to the collection itself, by using [`entry_options`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-options):

```
->add('keywords', CollectionType::class, [
  'allow_add' => true,
  'delete_empty' => true,
  'constraints' => [
    new Count(['min' => 1]),
  ],
  'entry_options' => [
    'constraints' => [
      new Regex(['pattern' => '/whateverpattern/']),
    ],
  ],    
])
```

Comment: Excellent! I've been using Symfony since 2.8 and I didn't figure this out. Worked great, thanks :)